# How to optimize a call to webGL.bufferData with a large amount of static vertex data (500k vertices)

Tags: performance, webgl

Hi all I am making a minecraft styled game, hence the large number of vertices in a single bufferData call.  I have already optimised things so that each vertice only has a single float32 attribute, that basically constitutes a vertice ID.  so 500k vertices only use 500k float32 attributes total.
The attributes in the vertex buffer are the equivalent of a series of ordered numbers that will never change.  It is just the amount of them that I send through that does.

The actual data for the minecraft style cubes is converted to a texture and passed in to the shader like that.  The shader does all the work of decoding the texture data and mapping it to each vertice.

I am currently getting 60fps in chrome running this lot, but I want to push it up to at least 2million vertices, so I need to somehow improve the performance of this lot.

When performance benchmarking in chome it appears that the cpu, not the gpu is the main bottleneck.   The call to bufferData consumes 33% of cpu resources and the call to texImage2d consumes 9.5% of cpu resources

I am looking for any ideas on how to improve this performance.

The link to project is [here](https://github.com/devblazer/Digger-VR)

The link to the js file that contains the webGl calls is [here](https://github.com/devblazer/Digger-VR/blob/master/src/app/lib/render/WebGL.js)

Comment: Relevant code needs to be in the question itself

Comment: The relevant code relates to most of the 5000 lines of code project, it was not known at time of writing that only a small portion would be relevant for the answer.  Pls consider things like this before down-voting peoples questions. @LJᛃ

Answer (score 2):

So I found the solution. You can use bufferSubData to update the vertice data in an existing vertexBuffer and just store, rebind and reuse that. However in my case the data in the vertexBuffer itself never changes, so all I needed to do was store the created vertexBuffer and rebind it whenever I want to use it, and absolutely no calls to any kind of buffer method are needed. Thereby eliminating the 33% cpu used for bufferData competely! Must still do further testing, but looking good so far.
Using this solution I was able to go as high as 14million vertices  and that's only because of other limitations not the call to teximage2d which is still only sitting at around 30% now.